# convert u32 to SystemTime

Tags: datetime, rust, epoch

In rust, how can I convert a `u32` Unix Epoch based value into a `std::time::SystemTime` ?

In my case, the `u32` value is from a [gzip header modified time](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1952#page-7).

---

Converse question: [How can I convert SystemTime::now() to an integer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61882364/how-can-i-convert-systemtimenow-to-an-integer-type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/time/struct.Duration.html) to [`SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html#associatedconstant.UNIX_EPOCH):

```rust
let time = SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH + Duration::from_secs(value);
```

Comment: Just to make sure. Neither `SystemTime` nor UNIX timestamps account for leap seconds, so this works out?

Comment: Yes, they're both based on UTC, meaning they do integrate leap seconds. They wouldn't account for leap seconds if they were based off of TAI.

Comment: @Caesar "Leap seconds" aren't a thing in UNIX timestamps. UNIX timestamps is just a count of the number of seconds past the UNIX epoch.